# React-Native TextInput prevent default on controlled input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, state, textinput

So I use my state to control a text input, but when I input a character, I don't want the character to show up right away. This is what is happening: 
1. I focus on text input
2. I type in a character.
3. The character quickly shows up in the text input.
4. The character quickly disappears and the value reverts back to the state because the state has not changed yet.

I am wondering how I can prevent the character from showing up in the first place if the state has not changed.

Here is a simple example:

```
state = {
 myValue: 'hello'
}

changedText = value => {
  //Nothing here yet
}

...
render(){
  return(
    <Input
      value={this.state.myValue}
      keyboardType="numeric"
      onChangeText={this.highIntervalDurationChange}
    />
  );
}
```

As you can see it's nothing complicated, I'm just trying to figure out a way to not have the pressed character not appear right away when it is pressed because currently it appears and reverts back to the state. (Obviously I will modify the state after I can figure out how to prevent default from happening.) I also tried setting editable to false and that just makes it so I can't edit it at all. Thanks!

Comment: Did you handle that as you wanted? I have same issue

Comment: I am facing same issue and didn't found an answer yet, my workaround was making a `<Text>` inside `<TextInpu>` with position absolute, making the TextInput text transparent and having the updated text inside the `<Text>`. It is not elegant and overcomplicated but works :)